# Untranslated address in PCIe

Tags: pci-express, nvme

I was going through the ATS feature which has been added in PCIe. I came across terms like Untranslated address and Physical address. Essentially the Translation agent on the host will convert Untranslated address received from the device to the Host's Physical address.

But my query is that the host-driver always gives the Physical address to the device, so who really provides this Untranslated address(Virtual address) to the device?

Eg: In case of "nvme", the nvme driver while preparing the PRP for a command, takes the physical address(and not Virtual address) from the host memory and submits the command in the Submission Queue.

So who really sends Virtual address to the device?

Answer (score 0):

ATS can be used for direct device assignment, assigning a hardware device to a virtual machine. In that case, the VM drivers can use guest-physical addresses as untranslated addresses, and the platform IOMMU translates them into host physical addresses, selecting the translation table based on the device's requestor ID.

With the PCIe PASID extension, untranslated addresses can also include a process address space ID (PASID). The IOMMU can take this ID into account when selecting the translation table. For example, this can be used to assign a device to process and have the process use IO virtual addresses with the device.